# How to automatically force audio through headphone jack?

Tags: audio

I am pretty new to using Raspberry and this may be a noob question. I figured out that to output audio through the headphone jack I need to change the setting using raspi-config. But whenever I reboot I need to change the configuration again to make it work. Is there any way of automatically configuring to output the audio through 3.5mm jack ? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

do the following

first remove `pulseaudio` if its installed and install `alsa alsa-utils`

When thats done do the following steps

```
snd_bcm2835
amixer cset numid=3 1
amixer cset numid=2 1
```

this ensures that you have the audio running over the headphone jacks and locks it

Comment: Removing parts of audio subsystem to pin the default output is like crushing a fly with a steam-roller.